# Limit of an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{k}}$ or prove that the limit does not exist.

---

First, I tried multiplying the $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ inside the summation, which resulted in $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{nk}}$. And I simply wrote out the first few terms to see if it is a telescoping series.
\begin{align*} 
  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{nk}} 
  &=\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{2n}}+\frac{1}{n+\sqrt{3n}}+...\\
\end{align*}
However, then I failed to see the pattern from here on. And I also thought of using L'Hôpital's rule, but I didn't exactly know how to implement it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

---

Comment: Try it the other way, pull out a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ from $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{k}}$.

Comment: Can you recognize this as a Riemann sum?

Comment: @GEdgar Do you mean somehow we can write it as an integral?

Comment: Try it and see...

Comment: look about this gif and think about the sum of the bars' areas http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Riemann_sum_%28leftbox%29.gif

Comment: @GEdgar I can only get as far as this: let $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(x)f(x+\sqrt{k})$. But then I don't know to deal with the k.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on from the comments:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{k}} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1 + \sqrt{k/n}}\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x}} dx\\
&= \left. 2(\sqrt{x} - \log(\sqrt{x}+1) \right|_0^1\\
&= 2(1-\log(2))
\end{align*}

Comment: I finally understand this! Thank you all for contributing!